# RESTORE to new DB with same login, access, and role permissions

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I am restoring a DB from a backup file using a SPROC. After the restore however I seem to be losing the login permissions etc. Is there a way to add these permissions into the restore SQL code below? This sproc exists outside the DB I am backing up, so I'm not sure how to add DB specific permissions to the restore.

```
RESTORE DATABASE @new_db_name 
FROM DISK = @file_path
WITH RECOVERY,

MOVE 'OriginalFile' TO @new_db_file,
MOVE 'OriginalFile_log' TO @new_db_log
```

I should add that the login and user that I need to add to the restored DB on the destination server does not exist on the original server where the backup file was created. However, this may not always be the case. After looking into this more I see that if the user/login does exist on the destination I will need to re-sync the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the login is present on Server A(Source) and Server B(Target) then the permissions should not be of issue.

If the login is NOT present on the Target, you can add them like such:

```
USE [Database Name]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Database role', 'Username'
```

Add role to user in database: [sp_addRoleMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) 
Add role to user at server level: [sp_addsrvrolemember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259597(v=sql.80).aspx)

The only outlier would be that the user account does not exist on Server B, then you would need to create and add them via a script as well.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned in my questoin that the source is restored to a new DB, so the login is not present for that reason (I presume). Since this is a new DB I cannot do USE [NEWDB], as the "NEWDB" name is actually a dynamic value that changes.

Comment: I restore databases a lot that have different names when I restore it.  Our users are AD Groups that have access. I don't mess with the accounts because they exist on both of our databases.

You could potentially use the fully qualified name as part of a script/job ?
eg: EXEC DBName.dbo.sp_addRoleMember

Also, I backup with these tags: WITH NOUNLOAD,COMPRESSION, COPY_ONLY

I need to look into the "With recovery though" as I do not use it when I restore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the login is to an interal id.  A login of the same name will not have the same internal id on different servers.  You need to remove the user from the role and then add that user name back.

If it is a domain AD group then you should not have to drop and reassign.  This is only for SQL users.